# How to Serialize Model in View and Pass to Controller Action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a very specific need to serialize a model in the view and then pass it to a controller action at some point. I can get it to work by doing several hacks but its not pretty.

My test controller action

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DefaultOptionValueRound defaultOptionValueRound = new DefaultOptionValueRound()
        {
            OptionId = 1835,
            OptionValueId = 40343
        };

        TestModel testModel = new TestModel()
        {
            DefaultOptionValueRound = defaultOptionValueRound
        };

        return View(testModel);
    }
```

The View

```
@using Common.Repository.Extensions
@model EngA.SandboxApplication.Controllers.TestModel

@Html.Hidden("DefaultOptionValueRound", Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DefaultOptionValueRound)))

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="SerializeModelTest.processOptionMag()"/>

<script language="javascript">

    SerializeModelTest = {

        processOptionMag: function () {

            //Testing: This Works
            //var defaultOptionValueRound = { OptionId: 1834, OptionValueId: 4034377 }
            //var data = JSON.stringify({ defaultOptionValueRound: defaultOptionValueRound });

            //This Does Not Work
            var defaultOptionValueRound = $("#DefaultOptionValueRound").val();
            var data = { defaultOptionValueRound: defaultOptionValueRound }; //Stringify Does not work either

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: "Post",
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessOptionMag", "SerializeModelTest")',
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

The problem is that the serialized model is returned in a stringify form already.

There must be an elegant way of doing this without me have to do JS string manipulation to make it work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the point of sending back exactly the same model to the controller that you just sent to the view? But you can just do this using `var data = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DefaultOptionValueRound)); $.post(yourUrl, data, function(data) { ... });` - no hidden inputs are required.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for your replay but I need to use a form element to save the "view state" (please don't go ballistic) for each row of a gird. I just provided the simplest of examples to get the point across. To give you the business context, I am presenting the user with default values based on the current database state but those values can change over time. So even if the database state would dictate new defaults by the time they accept the proposed default values, I must be able to save the defaults as they where at the time they were calculated and presented.

Comment: And for completeness, I may be passing back other parameters as well, not just the model.

Comment: Just get the 'default' values again from the database again in the POST method if you need them. Degrading performance by sending all that data across the wire and then back again unchanged is crazy.

Comment: Its a very minor amount of data compared to, lets say, an image... and its the only elegant solution I could think of. Not that crazy after all :)

Comment: Stephen. Sorry, I missed your post. Did you read my business context? First, I can not reliably regenerate the proposed values from the database. Second, the initial lookup is quite heavy and I do not want to repeat it if at all possible. Third, most of the time the sub-model I will be serializing will contain less data then a guid would take. Finally, there is no good alternative that I can think of. Storing state has its place when nothing else will work or work well. It just go overused in ASP.OLD days and now everyone is gun shy about the tiniest of implementations. Crazy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can un-stringify my result using JSON.Parse and then repackage it with other parameters for sending to the controller.

```
        var defaultOptionValueRound = $("#DefaultOptionValueRound").val();
        var data = JSON.stringify({ defaultOptionValueRound: JSON.parse(defaultOptionValueRound) });
```

Now everything works.